# Getting 'Error: AppleEvent handler failed' every time I run this script in Script Editor

Tags: macos, applescript

Been struggling to get this script to work. It's meant to batch export notes out of Apple Notes. Script is below.

```
// set things up
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var notesApp = Application('Notes');
notesApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;

// choose which notes
var notes = notesApp.notes;
var whichNotes = app.chooseFromList(notes.name(), { withPrompt: "Which Notes?", multipleSelectionsAllowed: true });


if (whichNotes) {

    // choose save location
    var saveWhere = app.chooseFolder().toString();
    
    if (saveWhere) {
    
        // loop through all notes
        for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
        
            // is this note one to be exported?
            if (whichNotes.indexOf(notes[i].name()) > -1) {
            
                // save file as html
                var filename = saveWhere+"/"+notes[i].name()+".html";
                var file = app.openForAccess(Path(filename), { writePermission: true });
                app.setEof(file, { to: 0 });
                app.write(notes[i].body(), {to: file});
                app.closeAccess(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A bunch of other people have used it with no problems.

Comment: Read the title.

Comment: It works for me in Monterey 12.6.1, although I don’t have many notes to test with.  Note that `includeStandardAdditions` just needs to target the current application, so the one targeting Notes.app should be removed.

Comment: The same error on my Catalina. I think, it is a **JXA bug**. Problematic is getting note names array (**notes.name()**). At least on Catalina as I tested. Exists AppleScript workaround which works without problems. If need, AppleScript code can be executed from JXA as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same script on 10.15.7. The issue is raised on notes.name().

I assume this is related to either too many notes (it used to work, but I created a lot of notes since), or some special char in the note title. But I did not managed to fix it with my notes.

I copied my version below.
(notice the replace to build a valid file name if your note title contain "/".)

```
// set things up
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var notesApp = Application('Notes');
notesApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;


// choose which notes
var notes = notesApp.notes;
this.console.log("before notes.name()")
var whichNotes = app.chooseFromList(notes.name(), { withPrompt: "Which Notes?", multipleSelectionsAllowed: true });
this.console.log("After notes.name()")

this.console.log("Let's do it") // view / show log / message tab

if (whichNotes) {

    // choose save location
    var saveWhere = app.chooseFolder().toString();
    
    if (saveWhere) {
    
        this.console.log("note count:"+notes.length) 
        // loop through all notes
        for(var i=0; i<notes.length; i++) {
        
            // is this note one to be exported?
            if (whichNotes.indexOf(notes[i].name()) > -1) {
            
                // save file as html
                
                var notename = notes[i].name().replace(/\//gi,'-')
                this.console.log("next:"+notename) // view / show log / message tab
                var filename = saveWhere+"/"+ notename +".html";
                var file = app.openForAccess(Path(filename), { writePermission: true });
                app.setEof(file, { to: 0 });
                app.write(notes[i].body(), {to: file});
                app.closeAccess(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```